# Sulla correttezza di "molto migliore"

Tags: grammar, comparison

Come la maggior parte degli utenti di Italian.SE sicuramente sapranno, l'uso di *molto migliore* e *molto maggiore* è grammaticalmente corretto (tranne il caso in cui *migliore* e *maggiore* sono usati come superlativi relativi), vedasi ad esempio [questo articolo della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/correttezza-molto-migliore-molto-maggiore).

Tuttavia nella mia esperienza, la maggior parte degli italiani è convinta, per qualche motivo, che il precedente sia un uso scorretto (di solito presentando argomenti sconclusionati del tipo "se sei maggiore non puoi diventare ancor più maggiore"). Questo include anche una percentuale non trascurabile degli insegnanti di italiano nelle scuole.

> **Q:** Dove ha avuto origine la "leggenda grammaticale" della scorrettezza di *molto maggiore/migliore*? E come mai si è diffusa a tal punto?

**EDIT** Per chiarire il tipo di risposta che mi aspetto: suppongo che a qualche punto (mi immagino al più tardi negli anni 50) qualche forma della regola "non si usa *molto migliore*" sia apparsa in qualche sussidiario o altro materiale didattico e da lì sia stata ricopiata in innumerevoli libri di scuola. Questo spiegherebbe il prestigio che la cosiddetta "regola" conserva ancora, specialmente (ma non solo) tra persone istruite. Per cui una risposta più che accettabile potrebbe essere trascrivere un tale documento (non è necessario che sia il primo, già una dimostrazione che quest'idea si sia in qualche modo infiltrata nelle "regole ufficiali" sarebbe abbastanza).

Ovviamente questa è solo una delle possibilità, e mi posso immaginare altre risposte possibili (e.g. una puntata malriuscita di [*Non è mai troppo tardi*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_%C3%A8_mai_troppo_tardi_(programma_televisivo)), in cui la regola viene esposta in modo possibilmente ambiguo...), per cui questo vuole essere solo un suggerimento, non l'unico tipo di risposta che accetterei.

Comment: Ah, sì? Puoi fare qualche esempio di questa convinzione? Ammetto che non la conoscevo.

Comment: https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070320083223AAxyR89 http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_196.html sono due esempi, in aggiunta alla già segnalata domanda alla Crusca (mi riferisco alle domande qui, non alle risposte). Persino il mio libro di grammatica delle medie diceva "...anche se molti la considerano scorretta, è invece una costruzione molto diffusa nella lingua italiana sin dai suoi inizi..." (o simili, sto andando a memoria)

Comment: È possibile che il problema origini dal fatto che alcuni non distinguono tra *maggiore* comparativo e *maggiore* superlativo

Comment: Grazie, mi era sfuggito.

Comment: Sono sicuro che almeno il 99% degli italiani e io tra quelli, di fronte alla locuzione “molto migliore” avrebbero un dubbio e, per evitare una possibile figuraccia, andrebbero col molto più rassicurante “molto meglio”.

Comment: Ngram, per quel che serve, mostra un uso molto più frequente di “molto meglio di", rispetto a “molto migliore di”. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=molto+meglio+di%2Cmolto+migliore+di&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmolto%20meglio%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmolto%20migliore%20di%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Non credo ci sia chi dubiti della correttezza di “Kareem Abdul Jabbar è molto più alto di me”, quindi anche di “Kareem Abdul Jabbar è molto migliore di me a basket”. Trovo che “molto migliore” sia discutibile se usato in senso avverbiale (dove si dovrebbe adoperare “molto meglio”), ma come aggettivo è certamente lecito.

Comment: @egreg Su questo penso siamo tutti d'accordo :). Tuttavia vengo corretto spesso, anche da persone di una certa istruzione, quando lo uso. Perciò sono curioso di sapere da dove venga quest'idea che sia scorretto.

Comment: Lo so che questo intervento è del tutto inutile, ma anche leggendo i vostri commenti faccio veramente fatica a capire come a qualcuno possa suonare scorretto. Per me è come svegliarmi una mattina e apprendere che c'è chi considera scorretto “il gatto è sul tavolo”. Fine del rant.

Comment: Credo sia un riflesso; da bambino qualcuno si è sentito dire che “Non mi piace la gavotta, ballare il minuetto è molto migliore” è scorretto e si deve usare “molto meglio”. Da qui la generalizzazione del divieto in qualsiasi altro contesto, per comodità di memoria. Quando insegno agli aspiranti insegnanti di scuola primaria, li metto sempre in guardia sul fatto che i ricordi di quegli anni restano impressi in profondità.

Comment: @DaG Il gatto è sul tavolo? Pussa via!

Comment: Nell'articolo della Crusca vengono nominati i "famigerati più migliore, più maggiore". Ricordo che da bambini, poiché non conoscevamo ancora bene i comparativi, li usavamo spesso e venivamo puntualmente corretti. Forse, come segnalato da @egreg, potrebbe trattarsi di una generalizzazione del divieto per essere sicuri di non sbagliare, una sorta di ipercorrettismo?

Comment: Ma siamo sicuri che il divieto non fosse per "più migliore"?

Comment: @Alchimista Più che possibile, ma quest'idea che "molto migliore" sia sbagliato è presente in un segmento non indifferente della popolazione, per cui il fraintendimento avrà avuto origine da qualche parte...

Answer (score 2):

Alle elementari mi hanno sempre insegnato a dire molto migliore, ma a non dire più migliore. Dicevano che si usava così in latino, e che migliore è un superlativo assoluto, che può essere rinforzato dal "molto" ma non aumentato dal "più". Nessuno direbbe molto buonissimo, per questo tutti pensano che sia errato.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! +1 per la testimonianza. Certo che questo è bizzarro, perché *melior* in latino è comparativo (il superlativo è *optimus*), e *migliore* è al più un superlativo relativo in italiano (ma anche un comparativo), certo non un superlativo assoluto.

Answer (score 0):

> **È vero quello che scrivi, molti sono convinti che l’utilizzo di “molto migliore” sia scorretto perché erroneamente considerano “migliore” solo come superlativo, trascurando la sua funzione anche di comparativo.**

Come è scritto anche nell’articolo dell’Accademia della Crusca che hai citato, **bisogna distinguere due casi**:

- Caso in cui “migliore”, “maggiore” o “peggiore” si usino come **COMPARATIVI**;
- Caso in cui si usino come **SUPERLATIVI**.

> **USO COME COMPARATIVI:**
>   **È giusto** dire: “Il cioccolato fondente è **molto migliore** rispetto a quello al latte”.
>
> **USO COME SUPERLATIVI:**
>   **È sbagliato** dire: “Il cioccolato fondente è **il più migliore**”, perché “il migliore” è già un superlativo, aggiungere “più” esprimerebbe due volte la stessa informazione grammaticale.

Può aiutare sapere che “migliore”, “peggiore”, “maggiore”, “minore” sono **comparativi e superlativi SINTETICI**.
Quindi:
migliore = “più buono”;
peggiore = “più cattivo”;
maggiore = “più grande”;
minore = “più piccolo”;
ecc.

Se sostituissimo la forma estesa alla frase sopra scritta: “Il cioccolato fondente è **molto più buono** (anziché molto migliore) rispetto a quello al latte”, la frase potrebbe “suonare” più naturale, pur essendo corrette entrambe le forme.
Questo può essere un piccolo trucco da utilizzare in caso di dubbi o se non si ha dimestichezza con la lingua.
Spero che questo possa essere di aiuto.

Comment: Non sono sicuro che questo risponda alla domanda: mi pare che all'OP sia ben chiaro che “molto migliore” è corretto. Quello che chiede è come sia nata e si sia diffusa «la "leggenda grammaticale" della scorrettezza» di questa espressione.

Comment: @DaG, come ho scritto nella mia risposta, molti sono convinti che l’uso sia scorretto perché considerano “migliore” solo come superlativo: la mia maestra delle elementari, quando lo usavo, mi correggeva e non voleva sentire ragioni. Ho voluto specificare perché è giusto utilizzarlo per aiutare la moltitudine di persone che, come notato da Denis Nardin e dall’Accademia della Crusca, ha ad oggi dei dubbi.

Comment: Tutto giusto, tutto bene, e apprezzo la tua intenzione di aiutare le moltitudini, ma non era questo l'oggetto della domanda di Denis.

Comment: @DaG, per precisione allora editerò la risposta spostando in cima ed evidenziando la parte in cui rispondo alla domanda di Denis, in modo che sia più chiaro per tutti.

Comment: Ok, I've cleaned up a bit the comments. Please try to keep the discussion civil, and if the discussion seems to go longer than intended, move to chat.

Answer (score -2):

La grammatica si evolve, attualmente nessuno usa molto migliore, e se lo fai vieni guardato un po' male o ci suona strano, al massimo molto meglio..

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie per la tua risposta! Hai una citazione per "nessuno usa molto migliore"? Perché non corrisponde alla mia esperienza.

Comment: Non trovo che "molto migliore" non sia in uso. Grammaticalmente, è equivalente a dire "sei molto più alto di tuo fratello".

Comment: Ciao qua tutti dicono sei meglio non molto migliore...

Comment: Un conto è fare "meglio", un'altro è fare "molto meglio". Allo stesso modo, uno è migliore o molto migliore. A voler essere precisi, "essere meglio" sarebbe sbagliato: "meglio" è un avverbio, non un aggettivo. Sei alto, non sei altamente: allo stesso modo sei migliore e non sei meglio.

Comment: In effetti la risposta segnala un errore comune. In effetti credo lo facciamo quasi tutti